# Camel Kafka Version 2.14.3 unable to read messages

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a Kafka cluster(version : 0.10.1.0), with 9 brokers and 10 partitions.

I tried consuming messages from a java application using camel kafka `2.14.3`. Here is my camel route

```
<route id="ReadFromTopic">
    <from uri="kafka:[[broker.list]]?topic=[[topic]]&amp;zookeeperHost=[[zookeeper.host]]&amp;zookeeperPort=[[zookeeper.port]]&amp;groupId=[[consumer.group]]&amp;consumerStreams=[[concurrency]]" />
    <log message="Message Read from kafka topic : [[topic]]" loggingLevel="INFO" />
    <log message=" BODY is ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
</route>
```

Route starts fine, but isn't reading any messages.

When I tried using camel kafka `3.0.1`, with route as follows, I was able to read messages

```
<route id="ReadFromTopic">
    <from uri="kafka:[[topic]]?brokers=[[broker.list]]&amp;groupId=[[consumer.group]]" />   
    <log message="read message : ${body}" />
</route>
```

Because of the dependencies I have, I can only use camel kafka `2.14.3`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Kafka) where the different options of Camel-Kafka depending on the version are listed.

Checkout the options for version 2.16 or older. The [component documentation for Camel 2.x](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/kafka-component.html) seems to be valid for 2.17 or newer.