# Camel Kafka : Unable to read messages from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a Kafka cluster(version : 0.10.1.0), with 9 brokers and 10 partitions.

I tried consuming messages from a java application using camel kafka `2.14.3`. Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This is only dependency I'm using related to camel Kafka. Below is the camel kafka consumer code.

```
<route id="ReadFromTopic">
    <from uri="kafka:[[topic]]?brokers=[[broker.list]]&amp;groupId=[[consumer.group]]" />   
    <log message="read message : ${body}" />
</route>
```

I'm using Kafka URI as specified in the docs https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html.

But below is the exception I get while loading the camel context

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: kafka://[[topic]]?brokers=[[broker.list]]&groupId=[[consumer.group]] due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: kafka://[[topic]]?brokers=[[broker.list]]&groupId=[[consumer.group]] due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{brokers=[[broker.list]]}]
```

It says `Unknown parameters=[{brokers=[[broker.list]]}]`. 
I tried with `camel-kafka 3.x`, it consumes fine. But I have to use camel kafka `2.14.3` in the production. Am I missing any dependencies or using wrong URI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right path in [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62381728/8035582). I am very surprised that the URI format of Camel Kafka has changed this much between 2.14.2 and newer versions of Camel 2.x. Perhaps because of newer Kafka versions?

You can see it on the `KafkaConfiguration` documentation of [version 2.24.3](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-kafka/2.24.3/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaConfiguration.html) and [version 2.14.3](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-kafka/2.14.3/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaConfiguration.html). On version 2.14.3 there is no getBrokers method to get a `brokers` parameter, so the error message you get is according to the version you use.

In contrast, on version 2.24.3 there is such a method and therefore it corresponds to the [component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/kafka-component.html) of newer Camel 2.x versions.

Unfortunately I did not find a component documentation of version 2.14.3, but perhaps you can construct it from the URI of your first question with the possible parameters of `KafkaConfiguration`.